Recovering from a dead Pixel 5a that shows as Google MTP when connected via USB
I have a Pixel 5a that simply went blank one day and will not power on.  Holding down any combination of buttons for various long periods of time does not work.  Charging on any charger does not work.  No blinks, sounds, nothing.
There is the smallest sign of life, however.  If I hold down the power button while connecting to a PC via USB, the PC detects it as an MTP device.

    =========================== USB Port4 ===========================

Connection Status        : 0x01 (Device is connected)
Port Chain               : 3-2-3-4

      ========================== Summary =========================
Vendor ID                : 0x18D1 (Google Inc.)
Product ID               : 0x4EE1
USB Version              : 3.2 Gen 1
Port maximum Speed       : SuperSpeed
Device maximum Speed     : SuperSpeed
Device Connection Speed  : SuperSpeed
Self powered             : no
Demanded Current         : 896 mA
Used Endpoints           : 4

      ======================== USB Device ========================

        +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Device Description       : MTP USB Device
Device Path              : \\?\USB#VID_18D1&PID_4EE1#17121JECB03087#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE)
Kernel Name              : \Device\USBPDO-34
Device ID                : USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1\17121JECB03087
Hardware IDs             : USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1&REV_0440 USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE1
Driver KeyName           : {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a}\0005 (GUID_DEVCLASS_WPD)
Driver                   : \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\WUDFRd.sys (Version: 10.0.22621.3672  Date: 2024-05-29)
Driver Inf               : C:\WINDOWS\inf\wpdmtp.inf
Legacy BusType           : PNPBus
Class                    : WPD
Class GUID               : {eec5ad98-8080-425f-922a-dabf3de3f69a} (GUID_DEVCLASS_WPD)
Service                  : WUDFWpdMtp
Enumerator               : USB
Location Info            : Port_#0004.Hub_#0010
Location IDs             : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(0803)#PCI(0004)#USBROOT(0)#USB(2)#USB(3)#USB(4), ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(GP19)#ACPI(XHC4)#ACPI(RHUB)#ACPI(PRT2)#USB(3)#USB(4)
Container ID             : {35828a75-1c9b-5299-ac2c-cba053d7bbbb}
Manufacturer Info        : (Standard MTP Device)
Capabilities             : 0x94 (Removable, UniqueID, SurpriseRemovalOK)
Status                   : 0x0180600A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_DISABLEABLE, DN_REMOVABLE, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem Code             : 0
Lower Filters            : WinUsb
HcDisableSelectiveSuspend: 0
EnableSelectiveSuspend   : 0
SelectiveSuspendEnabled  : 0
EnhancedPowerMgmtEnabled : 0
IdleInWorkingState       : 0
WakeFromSleepState       : 0
Power State              : D0 (supported: D0, D3, wake from D0)

        +++++++++++++++++ Registry USB Flags +++++++++++++++++
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\18D14EE10440
 osvc                    : REG_BINARY 01 01
 SkipContainerIdQuery    : REG_BINARY 01 00

        ---------------- Connection Information ---------------
Connection Index         : 0x04 (Port 4)
Connection Status        : 0x01 (DeviceConnected)
Current Config Value     : 0x01 (Configuration 1)
Device Address           : 0x1A (26)
Is Hub                   : 0x00 (no)
Device Bus Speed         : 0x02 (High-Speed) -> not true, see below in Connection Information V2
Number Of Open Pipes     : 0x03 (3 pipes to data endpoints)
Pipe[0]                  : EndpointID=1  Direction=IN   ScheduleOffset=0  Type=Bulk       wMaxPacketSize=1024  bInterval=0
Pipe[1]                  : EndpointID=1  Direction=OUT  ScheduleOffset=0  Type=Bulk       wMaxPacketSize=1024  bInterval=0
Pipe[2]                  : EndpointID=2  Direction=IN   ScheduleOffset=0  Type=Interrupt  wMaxPacketSize=28    bInterval=6
Data (HexDump)           : 04 00 00 00 12 01 20 03 00 00 00 09 D1 18 E1 4E   ...... ........N
                           40 04 01 02 03 01 01 02 00 1A 00 03 00 00 00 01   @...............
                           00 00 00 07 05 81 02 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 07 05   ................
                           01 02 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 07 05 82 03 1C 00 06   ................
                           00 00 00 00                                       ....

        --------------- Connection Information V2 -------------
Connection Index         : 0x04 (4)
Length                   : 0x10 (16 bytes)
SupportedUsbProtocols    : 0x04
 Usb110                  : 0 (no, port not supports USB 1.1)
 Usb200                  : 0 (no, port not supports USB 2.0)
 Usb300                  : 1 (yes, port supports USB 3.0)
 ReservedMBZ             : 0x00
Flags                    : 0x03
 DevIsOpAtSsOrHigher     : 1 (Device is operating at SuperSpeed or higher)
 DevIsSsCapOrHigher      : 1 (Device is SuperSpeed capable or higher)
 DevIsOpAtSsPlusOrHigher : 0 (Device is not operating at SuperSpeedPlus or higher)
 DevIsSsPlusCapOrHigher  : 0 (Device is not SuperSpeedPlus capable or higher)
 ReservedMBZ             : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 04 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 03 00 00 00   ................

    ---------------------- Device Descriptor ----------------------
bLength                  : 0x12 (18 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x01 (Device Descriptor)
bcdUSB                   : 0x320 (USB Version 3.2)
bDeviceClass             : 0x00 (defined by the interface descriptors)
bDeviceSubClass          : 0x00
bDeviceProtocol          : 0x00
bMaxPacketSize0          : 0x09 (9 bytes)
idVendor                 : 0x18D1 (Google Inc.)
idProduct                : 0x4EE1
bcdDevice                : 0x0440
iManufacturer            : 0x01 (String Descriptor 1)
 *!*ERROR  String descriptor not found
iProduct                 : 0x02 (String Descriptor 2)
 *!*ERROR  String descriptor not found
iSerialNumber            : 0x03 (String Descriptor 3)
 *!*ERROR  String descriptor not found
bNumConfigurations       : 0x01 (1 Configuration)
Data (HexDump)           : 12 01 20 03 00 00 00 09 D1 18 E1 4E 40 04 01 02   .. ........N@...
                           03 01                                             ..

    ------------------ Configuration Descriptor -------------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x02 (Configuration Descriptor)
wTotalLength             : 0x0039 (57 bytes)
bNumInterfaces           : 0x01 (1 Interface)
bConfigurationValue      : 0x01 (Configuration 1)
iConfiguration           : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
bmAttributes             : 0x80
 D7: Reserved, set 1     : 0x01
 D6: Self Powered        : 0x00 (no)
 D5: Remote Wakeup       : 0x00 (no)
 D4..0: Reserved, set 0  : 0x00
MaxPower                 : 0x70 (224 mA)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 02 39 00 01 01 00 80 70 09 04 00 00 03 06 01   ..9.....p.......
                           01 04 07 05 81 02 00 04 00 06 30 06 00 00 00 07   ..........0.....
                           05 01 02 00 04 00 06 30 06 00 00 00 07 05 82 03   .......0........
                           1C 00 06 06 30 00 00 00 00                        ....0....

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x00 (Interface 0)
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x03 (3 Endpoints)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x06 (Image)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x01 (Still Imaging device)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x01
iInterface               : 0x04 (String Descriptor 4)
 *!*ERROR  String descriptor not found
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 00 00 03 06 01 01 04                        .........

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x81 (Direction=IN EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0400 (max 1024 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 81 02 00 04 00                              .......

        ------ SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion Descriptor -------
bLength                  : 0x06 (6 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x30 (SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion Descriptor)
bMaxBurst                : 0x06 (up to 7 packets per burst)
bmAttributes             : 0x00 (The bulk endpoint does not define streams)
wBytesPerInterval        : 0x0000
Data (HexDump)           : 06 30 06 00 00 00                                 .0....

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x01 (Direction=OUT EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0400 (max 1024 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 01 02 00 04 00                              .......

        ------ SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion Descriptor -------
bLength                  : 0x06 (6 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x30 (SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion Descriptor)
bMaxBurst                : 0x06 (up to 7 packets per burst)
bmAttributes             : 0x00 (The bulk endpoint does not define streams)
wBytesPerInterval        : 0x0000
Data (HexDump)           : 06 30 06 00 00 00                                 .0....

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x82 (Direction=IN EndpointID=2)
bmAttributes             : 0x03 (TransferType=InterruptPeriodic)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x001C
bInterval                : 0x06 (32 microframes -> 4 ms)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 82 03 1C 00 06                              .......

        ------ SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion Descriptor -------
bLength                  : 0x06 (6 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x30 (SuperSpeed Endpoint Companion Descriptor)
bMaxBurst                : 0x00 (up to 1 packets per burst)
bmAttributes             : 0x00
wBytesPerInterval        : 0x0000 (0 bytes)
Data (HexDump)           : 06 30 00 00 00 00                                 .0....

      ---------- Binary Object Store (BOS) Descriptor -----------
bLength                  : 0x05 (5 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x0F (Binary Object Store)
wTotalLength             : 0x0016 (22 bytes)
bNumDeviceCaps           : 0x02
Data (HexDump)           : 05 0F 16 00 02                                    .....

        ------------- USB 2.0 Extension Descriptor ------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x10 (Device Capability Descriptor)
bDevCapabilityType       : 0x02 (USB 2.0 Extension)
bmAttributes             : 0x06
 LPMCapable              : 1 (Link Power Management protocol is supported)
 BESLAndAlternateHIRD    : 1 (BESL & Alternate HIRD definitions are supported)
 BaselineBESLValid       : 0 (not valid)
 DeepBESLValid           : 0 (not valid)
 BaselineBESL            : 0
 DeepBESL                : 0
Data (HexDump)           : 07 10 02 06 00 00 00                              .......

        ----- SuperSpeed USB Device Capability Descriptor -----
bLength                  : 0x0A (10 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x10 (Device Capability Descriptor)
bDevCapabilityType       : 0x03 (SuperSpeed USB Device Capability)
bmAttributes             : 0x00
 Bit 0 Reserved          : 0x00
 Bit 1 LTM Capable       : 0x00 (no)
 Bit 7:2 Reserved        : 0x00
wSpeedsSupported         : 0x0F (Low-Speed, Full-Speed, High-Speed, SuperSpeed)
bFunctionalitySupport    : 0x01 (lowest speed with all the functionality is 'Full-Speed')
bU1DevExitLat            : 0x01   (less than 1 µs)
wU2DevExitLat            : 0x01F4 (less than 500 µs)
Data (HexDump)           : 0A 10 03 00 0F 00 01 01 F4 01                     ..........

      -------------------- String Descriptors -------------------
none

Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any volumes I can access.  I assume this is because the phone is locked with a swipe pin.
Is there anything that can be done with the phone in this state?  Any way to unlock it?  (I have the pin, just nowhere to swipe it.)

MTP is only provided by Android after it has been booted so the device is up and running - thus you have a broken-screen. If you have a pin or a password set (not a pattern) you can try an USB keyboard for entering it and unlock it.
